# Van Kampen diagram/Van Kampen lemma

Tags: group-theory

Question: Consider the following presentation $G=\langle a,b|aba^{-1}b^{-1} \rangle$. Does there exist a Van Kampen diagram over the presentation whose boundary label is the word $w=a^{2}ba^{-1}b^{-2}a^{-1}b$?

What I tried: First, the relators are $aba^{-1}b^{-1}$, $bab^{-1}a^{-1}$ and all their cyclic permutations. rewriting the word w in its full form gives $w=aaba^{-1}b^{-1}b^{-1}a^{-1}b$. Since the words $aba^{-1}b^{-1}$ and $ab^{-1}a^{-1}b$ are relators, they are equal to the identity 1 of G. It follows that $w=a(aba^{-1}b^{-1})b^{-1}a^{-1}b=1.1$ which is just the identity 1 in G and hence $w=1$ in G. By the Van Kampen diagram, yes there is a Van Kampen diagram over G whose boundary label is w. Can someone please help and see if the approach I used is the correct one? Subsidiary question: Since $w=1$ in G, can we say that the word  $w=a^{2}ba^{-1}b^{-2}a^{-1}b$ is a relator? Also, anyone knows where (documentation, book, etc) I can solve more of these similar problems?

I appreciate your help.

Comment: There is no general efficient method for writing words that are know to be the identity in $G$ as products of conjugates of defining relators. More formally, you can construct examples in which this problem is arbitrarily more difficult than proving that $w =_G 1$.

Comment: @Derek Holt, OK sounds good. Is there any book with or without solutions I can use to solve problems perhaps more difficult  than this one, related to drawing Van Kampen diagram, finding pieces and relators, and also given a presentation, find whether they satisfy small cancellation conditions C'($\lambda$) or $C(p)$?

Comment: Dijnola did you ever find more references for this?